# Are static html pages required to build a Drupal

Tags: 7, theming, panels, performance

Are static html pages required to build a Drupal based social networking site or should I go about creating content (views or modules etc) and assigning regions to them. I have already created a theme based on Zen.

Comment: _"Are static html pages required to build a Drupal based...site"_ No of course not, what makes you think they are?

Comment: @Clive thats what i thought...but my colleagues insist on that...their point of view is that once make static html then integrate them with Drupal for better control or whatever...   
to me it makes no sense though...there are about 30 pages each...its pointless writing custom page.tpl.php for them each and then calling every view, every module output from within them, which being quite complex would also be difficult to achieve and a sheer waste of time...so how do i make them understand this?

Comment: So are they planning on building a fully static site, _then_ converting it to Drupal? That does seem like quite a large waste of time. I'm not really sure how you'd convince them otherwise if that's their opinion though; some people still prefer the 90's ways of doing things, can't be helped :)

Comment: yups...its seems a tough ask

Comment: @Clive it have been years and you didn't make it an answer, so I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, of course they aren't.

I encountered approach like "Let's convert this psd to html site and then Drupalize it!", too. But it usually was a failure, and took way too long for the result it gave. Even worse if designers insisted on exactly the same HTML output, not just the same look.

So no, they are not needed, and this approach might even be harmful for the project.